# select rows from multiple inputs without cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

Small introduction.

I have two tables one called date_time with column date_time_key containing 15 minutes timestaps in unix format
and second table agents containing users' data including login_time and logout_time.

My question is. Can I create 15 minutes statistics how many users were logged?
At the moment I am able to get list of unix timestaps from date_time. and separately get login and logout time from second table.

```
select date_time_key from date_time
where label_date = '2018-07-23';


select start_time, end_time from agents;
```

I hope you can understand,
Thanks for any help

Edit:

Table date_time constains timestamp in unix epoch format (1532510096) in 15 minutes steps.

I would like to have output as

```
Date Time Count_of_agents
2018-07-24 10:00 20 
2018-07-24 10:15 22
etc ..
```

Comment: i am sorry. It's Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. Finnally i created my own solution.

Simplified:

```
with X as 
(
   -- get all 15 minutes timestamps i want 
   select start_time, end_time
   from agents
   where start_time > 1532476903 and end_time <  1532559703
)

select label_date, count(label_date)
from date_time 
-- join agent to date_time table if timestamp lies between agents login and logout
right join X on X.start_time < dt.date_time_key   
and X.end_time > dt.date_time_key
group by label_date
order by label_date
```

It's not efficient or beautiful solution, but works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date_time_key, start_time, end_time are date format, to get all agents info you could do something like :

```
select a.*,
b.date_time_key
from agents a,
date_time b
where start_time <= b.date_time_key
and end_time >= b.date_time_key
```

If date_time_key is a timestamp in character format then you would need to format it, in oracle it would look something like this :

```
select a.*,
b.date_time_key
from agents a,
date_time b
where a.start_time <= TO_DATE(b.date_time_key,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
and a.end_time >=  TO_DATE(b.date_time_key,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

The SQL is untested and is made with oracle functions in mind, please provide more details as to what rdbms you use if that does not help you

Comment: Thank you for comment,
Actually all dates have unix epoch format (1532509303). 
Table 'date_time' contains unix timestamps in 15 minutes steps . 

As output i would like have something like 
Date Time count_of_users
2018-07-24 10:00 20
2018-07-24 10:15 22
etc. 

i hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to convert from unix epoch to a date/time format.  If so:

```
select dt.dte, count(*)
from (select dt.*,
             (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00') + date_time / (24 * 60 * 60) as dte
      from date_time dt
     ) dt left join
     agents a
     on dte >= login_time and dte <= logout_time
where dt.label_date = '2018-07-03'
group by dt.dte
order by dt.dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT a.date_time_key unixdate,count(*) count_of_agents
FROM date_time a, agents b
WHERE b.end_time>=a.date_time_key and b.start_time<=a.date_time_key+15*60
GROUP BY by a.date_time_key
```

How to convert unixtime to oracle date you can find in internet. Here is [example](https://community.oracle.com/thread/302756?start=0&tstart=0)